# Pushing an Existing Page in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm making a text based game on Xamarin.Forms. 
currently my main page has a "Start Game" Button.
and I'm using NavigationPage to go to the game page, like so:

```
  Navigation.PushAsync(new GamePage());
```

I'm Trying to add a "Resume Game" Button that will go the game page but with all the data that exists in it.
basically i want it so that when you exit the "Game Page" the data doesn't wipe. and you can resume it at anytime.
I'm wondering if this at all possible as the data on the Game Page is to much to just call it all when invoking the page.

Comment: How do you exit from GamePage?

Comment: @DennisSchröer normally using back button. i want to make it so that even if you close the app you can still pick up where you left off the previous game.

Comment: Then you need to save your data in a database and load it every time the page is created or navigated to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define game data on GamePage's constructor. And you can easily pass your data to this GamePage via constructor. For Example :

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new GamePage(gameData));
```

and your data does not wipe.

Comment: I already know about this method but since the data is to much and in different formats I don't think it can be done.

Comment: Yeah but as @Feuillebug mention , you can store the state of your data every page loaded. And you can save this data to localdb (sqlite etc.). After App Life Cycle broken you can check the state and you can get your data and interact with user ask to load his data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to load an existing page directly into Xamarin. You will need to think about another way to store the game state.

The easiest way is to use a text file (xml, json...) that you will load and pass as parameter to your page.

Don't forget to save the state in the different events of the App Life Cycle to avoid data loss.